# How to Prevent SWF File from Loading Again After Button Click

Tags: file, flash, loading

I'm programing in ActionScript 3, and loading a swf file. I want to know how to prevent an already loaded swf file from loading again after clicking on a button. (ie. I click on the About button, which loads the swf file called "about". I click on the About button again, and the About swf file doesn't load, because its already loaded) This is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sid.

Comment: Why don't you just create a variable containing the current swf filename or ID? You may then check what is the value of this variable and if it isn't equal to the last loaded swf file, you can load the new file. Otherwise, just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
public class MainClass extends MovieClip
{
   .... 
   private var aboutDlg:AboutClass = null;


  private function onAboutClick(e:Event):void
  {
     if (null != aboutDlg)
     {
        aboutDlg.visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
         // load dialog and assign aboutDlg to it
     }
  }
}
```